# How to convert a Kotlin source file to a Java source file. (Kotlin Bytecode from tools is hidden) any other way will be quite helpful

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

[image]

How to find activity main.Xml and Activity main.xml in android studio? Previously it was there but after the update I can't find it. A screenshot of Android studio is attached below.

How to convert a Kotlin source file to a Java source file?? Tools>>Kotlin>>Kotlin bytecode is not accessible as of now.

I wanted to write code in java in android studio

Comment: "it's only supporting Kotlin and not java presently" -- Android Studio supports both Java and Kotlin.

Comment: Why are you trying to open a Kotlin generated class as Java? Sounds like an XY Problem.

Comment: Try looking at [Converting a Kotlin File to Java](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/convert-to-java).

Comment: Due to the above issue, I can't find activity_main.xml or MainActivity.java                             Where to write their respective codes?

Comment: Android Studio supports Java

Comment: It's hard to understand what do you mean. First, as others said, Java is supported by Android Studio. Second, if it wouldn't, then how would it make sense to convert from a supported language to an unsupported one? I guess you mean something much different.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.